# Using a byte stream to another process, to offload the processing load

Tags: java

I have any extremely large amount of byte data that I want offload reading onto another process. So I wanted to open some type of stream to this other process, and then when I am done close the stream. The other process can read the byte array data and process separately from the main process.

What is the best type of stream to use? I was thinking about a buffered byte array stream. Are there limitations for this type of stream?

Is best to use a buffered stream for performance?

Is there a good example of the proper way to perform this type of operation?

Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Do you want the two processes to communicate over the network? Maybe sockets? What about pipes?

Comment: Basically it is a one way communications, of just blasting this byte stream to the other process.  There really doesn't need to be any communications between them except for the data starting and stopping.  Do think that would be appropriate for sockets or pipes?

Comment: I haven't done pipes/ sockets in a long time. If both processes are on the same box, what is the most efficient way of sending the bytes? Would the pipes be very efficient? If it's another box then maybe sockets would be appropriate??

Comment: Why do you want to process this with another process rather than with another thread. It would be much simpler to process in a separate thread in the same process.

Comment: Sorry I did mean separate Thread, not process. What would be the most efficient way  of offloading as much processing as possible onto the other thread? Can  you have a bufferedbytstream with a pipe?

Comment: @user565660 if you meant thread not process, please update the qeestion summary and description. Also, how are you getting the byles? Via an API? A file? A stream?